# How can I create a strong Boolean in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, scope, boolean

I understand that I cannot have something like :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) BOOL didSomethingHappen;
```

What I am trying to replicate is that in a particular ViewController which segues from a TableViewCell, if a particular action was committed, then set the BOOL `didSomethingHappen` to True. Now, if you go to the same View Controller but from a different TableViewCell, then didSomethingHappen should be the default value.

I thought what I need is a nice strong Boolean for every individual ViewController object. Can someone tell me just how to achieve this? I'm very new to Objective C.

To Recap.

```
|    Table Cell 1    | ----------> |    VC with didSomethingHappen     |
|    Table Cell 2    | ----------> |    VC with !didSomethingHappen    |
|    Table Cell 3    | ----------> |    VC with didSomethingHappen     |
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(strong)` won't help you here.  `(strong)` is to do with the way in which assignment to a property deals with the reference count.  If you assign an object to a `(strong)` property then the reference count of the assigned object is increased, preventing it from being released while the property holds a reference.  A `(weak)` property won't do this, so the referenced object may be released while the property holds the reference.  In this case the property will be set to nil.

As a BOOL is an intrinsic type and not an object, its value is simply assigned to the property, the property does not hold a reference; so you can't make it `(strong)` or `(weak)`.

Properties exist per object instance.  So, you need to ensure that the action for each cell instantiates a new copy of the view controller and assigns bool appropriately before invoking the segue (or as part of `prepareForSegue`).

Comment: Yup. Went with a property after this. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap BOOL into NSNumber* for example and create a strong pointer to that object. Check for `numberWithBool` and `boolValue` functions https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: While this will allow the property to be declared (strong) it won't help with the actual problem which is to have properties per VC instance - that is implicit

Comment: Hey, Paulw is right. Though it was a decent intermediate fix, it didn't give me the exact thing I was looking for. Still, thanks for that. It gave me a good idea to think about when working with Boolean again.